# Gigabyte GA-Z68X-UD7-B3 Motherbaord and Archlinux UEFI boot

Tags: linux, boot, motherboard, bios, arch-linux

Is it possible to UEFI boot Archlinux using the Gigabyte GA-Z68X-UD7-B3 motherboard with an SSD attached.

I have tried several things specified on their wiki, including EUFI boot from a USB drive, however, I can't seem to get into a UEFI shell to set this up.  I try to boot from the Archlinux disk in UEFI and get the message "Error loading \EFI\archiso\vmlinuz.efi Device error".  There are 4 UEFI boot shell options from the Archlinux disk, and all return the same or similar error message and won't boot.  I am guessing that the board has very limited EFI support, but I can't find a specific answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I've found one can only boot to EFI for installations via DVD on the Gigabyte Z68-UD7-B3 motherboard.

To do so, go into the BIOS and configure the DVD drive to boot to EFI. Now you can install any OS using GPT and EFI.